# default virtualhost overlap on port 19000. Oracle OHS server failed to start

Tags: oracle, hyperion

I am working on enable ssl for Oralce EPM11121 OHS server.

While after configuration, want to restart the OHS server. Found it can not be start and got below error message from ohs_component.log

```
[2015-08-26T11:13:51.3062+08:00] [OHS] [INCIDENT_ERROR:32] [OHS-9999] [worker.c] [host_id: vmhkhypirdv1] [host_addr: 172.23.18.212] [pid: 21253] [tid: 47937310527456] [user: hyperion] [VirtualHost: main] (98)Address already in use:  make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:19000
[2015-08-26T11:13:51.3063+08:00] [OHS] [INCIDENT_ERROR:20] [OHS-9999] [worker.c] [host_id: vmhkhypirdv1] [host_addr: 172.23.18.212] [pid: 21253] [tid: 47937310527456] [user: hyperion] [VirtualHost: main]  no listening sockets available, shutting down
[2015-08-26T11:13:51.3063+08:00] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [OHS-9999] [core.c] [host_id: vmhkhypirdv1] [host_addr: 172.23.18.212] [pid: 21253] [tid: 47937310527456] [user: hyperion] [VirtualHost: main]  Unable to open logs
```

And OHS server failed to start. console~OHS~1.log have below error message

```
[Wed Aug 26 11:13:51 2015] [crit] (20014)Internal error: WL SSL Init failed for server: (null) on 0
[Wed Aug 26 11:13:51 2015] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 19000, the first has precedence
[Wed Aug 26 11:13:51 2015] [warn] Errors will be logged into /u01/app/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/httpConfig/ohs/diagnostics/logs/OHS/ohs_component/ohs_component.log
```

Anyone know how to find the overlap one listen 19000? And make OHS server can be startup?

I already tried `>lsof -i :19000` but it returns nothing. Any other method that can find the configuration might listen to 19000?

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out where the wrong configuration.

I carelessly commented out 'Listen 19000' in file `{EPM_ORALCE_INSTANCE}/httpConfig/ohs/config/OHS/ohs_component/ssl.conf`

Should comment Listen.

`# OHS Listen Port`

`# Listen 19000`